# Origen de los chilenismos "patero" y "hacer la pata"

Tags: modismos, chile

En Chile usamos habitualmente la expresión **hacer la pata** con el sentido de *"adular"*. Hay una entrada en el [Diccionario de la RAE](https://dle.rae.es/pata#8ajGWQL), donde se aclara que es un chilenismo pero no se explica el origen.

Muy cercana, también está la palabra **patero**, *"adulador, lisonjero"*, que también se incluye en el [diccionario](https://dle.rae.es/patero?m=form), aunque mostrando juntas dos entradas con significados muy distintos. Aquí sí se ofrece un origen, dice "*de pato*".

Por ejemplo

> Se quedó y me hizo la pata descaradamente. (En "Profesión: Soltera" de Claudia Aldana)

En Etimologias de Chile las entradas de "patero" son más bien opiniones sin referencia. En otras partes se sugiere que proviene del lunfardo y hay quien dice que tiene alguna relación con "empate".

¿De donde provienen estas expresiones?

Comment: En Argentina "hacer la pata a alguien" significa ayudarlo o acompañarlo, en general en una tarea difícil o aburrida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según [esta página](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?patero), el origen de "patero" y "hacer la pata" estaría relacionado con el inglés "pat" (dar palmaditas):

> PATERO
> En Chile, la palabra "patero" es usada para referirse a alguien adulador. Es muy común en ese país decir algo así como "Eres un patero. Te vi
> haciéndole la pata al jefe". Uno pensaría que esta expresión tiene algo que ver con los pies, pero no es así. Tiene que ver con las manos. "Patero"
> viene del verbo ingles "pat" que significa "dar palmaditas".